# file not found while packing textures

Tags: texturing

I want to pack textures into a blend file. But it's telling me source not found even though the textures can be seen on the object properly and the textures are present in the folder.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just make sure the file is still located there. Blender loads images into memory, so they're visible even when deleted. But cannot be packed and will disappear when Blender is closed.

Comment: @JachymMichal I closed and reopened Blender, the problem didn't go away: the program is looking for a texture that shows up nowhere in the file. I had to go into the SCENE panel to delete a lot of unwanted stuff. In v.2.9 the PURGE ALL function doesn't seem to work very well.